# Flutter + webrtc room video call

Tags: flutter, webrtc

Im find https://github.com/cloudwebrtc/flutter-webrtc for use webrtc in flutter. But in repository, the sample is only peer to peer with 2 devices. I have build app for my customer for video call with many people. It's possible use this package for build video conference (2+) in flutter?

Comment: oh, you use webrtc mesh or what is solution? I have research but it to be quite complex.

Comment: @ThiagoFreitas, How did you solved that?

Comment: Yes, you can conference call with the help of that demo.  But for the conference call, you need to do customization on it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to establish a video call with many people using WebRTC and this package.

One approach would be to create a new RTCPeerConnection for every new peer in your room.
Check out this [example](https://github.com/lnogueir/webrtc-socketio-sample), it does exactly that.

However, since WebRTC is intended for peer-to-peer, this solution is not scalable at all, because you are going to be creating new peer connections exponentially.
With ~6 people, the quality of your call will already be terrible.
If your intention is to have a conference room, you should really look into using a [Selective Forwarding Unit (SFU)](https://webrtcglossary.com/sfu/), if you plan to be scalable at all.

Checkout [Janus VideoRoom](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/docs/videoroom.html) plugin for an open-source SFU implementation, just be aware that it's a bit cumbersome to set it up.

Answer (score -3):

For room video call, or live stream... you have to use a Media server to make it, webrtc just allow 2 peer, need a Media server to be an intermediaries

Answer (score -8):

unfortunately, you cannot use it for 2+ communication, because the main idea of webRTC is connect two sides through P2P.

Comment: please make your suggestions in comments

Comment: This is untrue. There are multiple architectures that u could implement to have multiple participants in a call

Comment: Ok..So is it possible to stream music using web rtc?

Comment: @JalakamKiran Yes definitely But why would you do that.

Comment: I was thinking of making a kind of group session for music. Just like Spotify group sessions.